# making bootstrap 4 input like material search field, transition animation issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i was trying to make bootstrap form input like material design search field. i have managed to make it but i guess there is a small issue with focus state and that is when i click the field, the underline animation runs smooth but, when i click outside of it the animation takes two steps to play. here is the code sample to understand better (i have downloaded bootstrap locally using npm)

in html =>

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mt-5">
    <i type="submit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

in scss =>

```
.d-flex {
    align-items: center;
}

.form-control {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4dd1e1;
    transition: border-color 0.2s linear;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

i.fa-search {
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

so, how can i fix this ?

Comment: Your code works normally on my computer  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `transition: border-color 0.2s linear;` into `.form-control`

```
.form-control {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: border-color 0.2s linear; /* moved form :focus */
}
```

Because your animation activates only on `:focus`, but whithout `:focus` the `.form-control` doesn't now about animation and do the transformation harshly.

Comment: thanks for your solution. i found transition property in .form-control and transition from border-color to border-bottom working.